# Is every quasiconcave function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ monotonic or else monotonically increasing and then monotonically decreasing?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

If the answer to the title is no, then the alternative is there is some interval on which the function is strictly decreasing and then strictly increasing, in which case it would not be quasiconcave as its minimum would not be at one of the end points of the interval, correct?

Comment: I am not sure about what are you asking, but, every concave function is quasiconcave, in particular $f(x) = -x^2$ is quasiconcave and is not monotonic.

Comment: @davius However, there is some $t\in\Bbb R$ such that $\left.f\right\rvert_{(-\infty,t]}$ is increasing and $\left. f\right\rvert_{[t,\infty)}$ is decreasing.

Comment: See chapter 3 here: https://www.genconv.org/files/Crouzeix_continuity.pdf.